# I got error while trying to put background color in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the dataframe which i have used :

[image]

i have tried following code :

```
def color_red_or_green(val):
    color = 'green' if val >= 70 else 'orange' if val < 70 & val >= 40 else "red"
    return 'color: %s' % color
week2_Percentage.style.apply(color_red_or_green, subset = ['availability'])
```

Which maps condition of the column name **availbility** for background color but got following error :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apply function is performed "column-wise, row-wise, or table-wise" according to its [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html). In your if else statement to determine color, the whole column "availability" is used, so there are all values at once in a series, not only a single one.

The usage of `&` doesn't work here, you need to use `and`.

Instead of apply, you need to use [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap.html) to format single elements based on conditions:

```
def color_red_or_green(val):
    color = 'green' if val >= 70 else 'orange' if val < 70 and val >= 40 else "red"
    return 'color: %s' % color

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["week", "availability"],
                       data=[[2, 10], [2, 100], [2, 60], [2, 70]])
df.style.applymap(color_red_or_green, subset = ['availability'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Johannes Schock, i got the solution with your help.